Is it possible to contact a human at Experian?
I signed up for an Experian account, but at some point during onboarding, it gives me the error:

Oops, we're sorry!
We have encountered an irrecoverable system error. Please note that your order has been canceled. Sorry about the inconvenience.
Call us toll-free at 1-866-617-1894
Hours of operation:
Mon - Fri: 6 am to 8 pm PT
Sat - Sun: 8 am to 5 pm PT


I always get the error after this screen:

When I call the number provided, the phone tree is impossible to get anywhere to a human. I even mailed a letter to Experian explaining the situation, but they have not responded. That was months ago.
Edit: I figured it out, you have to say you have a dispute. That gets you to a human.

Have you checked that you're talking to the real Experian website?

You can talk to a human at any website, as long as you’re a customer of their company. Customers are people who pay them money.

You might want to make that last paragraph an Answer. Also, in many modern phone trees, the keyword "representative" will get you to a human, though there may be a long wait on the queue.

@MikeScott That’s not always true. Try talking to a human at Amazon.

I figured it out, you have to say you have a dispute. That gets you to a human.
Either that or mail a letter which will presumably be read by a human at some point, but the timeline on a response via mail is much greater.
